# JavaFX - Access FXML item from remote Java class

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am fairly new to JavaFX and SceneBuilder and currently working on a project using these, but I will try to translate my issue to an easier scenario:

Let's assume that:

- I have used SceneBuilder to create a **Label with fx:id -> some_label** and a **Button with fx:id -> new_object** that will automatically be created in the *FXMLDocument.fxml*.
- I created a new java class *RemoteObject.java*, each RemoteObject having:

  ```
  int unique_id;
  Button some_button = new Button("Remote button");
  ```
- Inside the *FXMLController.java* I will have:

  ```
  @FXML
  public Label some_label;

  @FXML
  //this will be the handler for Button new_object 
  //which created using SceneBuilder
  public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) 
  {
      << create a new RemoteObject here >>
      << add RemoteObject.some_button to the scene >>
  }
  ```
- The main *FooApp.java* class would look like:

  ```
  public class FooApp extends Application {

      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

          Scene scene = new Scene(root);

          stage.setScene(scene);
          stage.show();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }

  }
  ```
- After running the program and pressing the **new_object** button, the result should look like:

[image]

The question is, how should the **RemoteObject.some_button**'s handler be implemented in order to change **some_label**'s caption (for example to **RemoteObject.unique_id**) on click?

Comment: I am guessing here-> When you create the `Button` go ahead and `newButton.setOnAction((event)->{//code goes here});`

Comment: I am setting a handler for the button inside the **RemoteObject** class, but my problem is trying to cast a variable from **FXMLController** inside that handler.